# How to fill in the table correctly

Tags: python, sqlite

Can you please tell me how to correctly fill in the table in the database from the `.CSV` file?
I have a database consisting of:
[image]

"ID"    integer NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY("ID" AUTOINCREMENT)

There is a `.CSV` file:

[image]

I connect to the database and read the given file:

```
con = sqlite3.connect(databasename)
table_count_before = con.execute("select * from test").fetchall()
cur = con.cursor()
with open(filename_csv, 'r') as f:
    dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
    test_csv = [(i['Model'], i['Price'], i['Format']) for i in dr]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO test (ID, Vendor, Model, Type, Standart, Format, " 
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
                "ON CONFLICT(Model) DO UPDATE SET "
                "ID = ?, Vendor = ?, Type = ?, Standart = ?, Format = ?;", test_csv)
con.commit()
con.close()
```

It turns out that I need to add a line from the file, focusing on the models that are not in the database, and if there is, then replace this line, in short, if there is no such model, insert the line, if there is something update / replace.
I don't need the `"Price"` column at all, but I can't remove it from `.CSV.`

In Pycharm I get the error:

`sqlite3.OperationalError: ON CONFLICT clause does not match any PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE constraint`

Please help me to solve this issue, I can't. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impose `UNIQUE` constraint on `Model` column.

```
CREATE TABLE test (
    ID       INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    Vendor   TEXT,
    Model    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    Type     TEXT,
    Standart TEXT,
    Format   TEXT
)
```

Without any constraints, there will be no `CONFLICT`.

Then:

```
    conn = sqlite3.connect('main.db')

    test_csv = []

    with open(filename_csv, 'r') as f:
        dr = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=';')
        for i in dr: 
            test_csv.append(
                (
                    '', i['Model'], '', i['Price'], i['Format'],
                    '', '', i['Price'], i['Format']
                )
            )
    
    conn.executemany(
        "INSERT INTO test (Vendor, Model, Type, Standart, Format) " 
        "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) "
        "ON CONFLICT(Model) DO UPDATE SET "
        "Vendor = ?, Type = ?, Standart = ?, Format = ?;", 
        test_csv
    )   

    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

It should work. (tested)

Don't forget `executemany` requires iterable of iterables and you should provide a value for each `?`.

Comment: error: `sqlite3.OperationalError: near "VALUES": syntax error`

Comment: updated the code in my request, now I'm using it

Comment: No, just this error, I created a table at your request, and I am trying to fill the table using my code, I updated the code in my question

Comment: @AlexRebell I just tested it and made an edit.

Comment: I can't understand, I copied everything as you wrote, but I have an error again ... I don't understand what is wrong :(

`, i['Model'], '', i['Price'], i['Format'],
`NameError: name 'i' is not defined`

Comment: Just an `NameError`. Related to `test_csv = [(i['Model'], i['Price'], i['Format']) for i in dr]`. What I did was `i = f.readline().split(';')`.

Comment: @AlexRebell I copied and pasted the full code snippet of mine. :)

Comment: God, how stupid I am, I realized my mistake, I did not formalize the cycle in the right way...Thank you very much! It would be possible to put you 10 points, I would put it without hesitation!

Comment: @AlexRebell Accepting is more than enough. Thanks, buddy!

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the script you used to create your table ? cause i can spot two potential issues:

1. Your CSV contains **3** rows while your table has **5**, unless you've
   set a default value for the two missing the script won't work.
2. The **ON CNFLICT** part of the query won't work unless you have already
   some **CONSTRAINT**s for your fields.

Comment: I recreated the table, as pointed out in his answer @GyuHyeon Choi

Comment: So the idea to overcome the cardinality number of the columns of @GyuHyeon was to **edit** the csv first before uploading it to the data table, right ? It will definitely work but it's not very clean and easily portable if you're going to repeat the same process for other files. I would suggest that you look at pandas as an alternative, and in your case this might help [Github\pandas_issues](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2981)

Comment: Thank you, I will definitely take this into account!